# The word "Note" causes Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL insert statement:

INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, LastName, Note) VALUES ('Sam', 'Jones', 'Works Mondays Only');

If I run the above statement as is, MS Access 2013 generates this error message: 
  Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

But if I put brackets around [Note] it works.
IF I change the name to fNote without brackets.....It works. (could be jNote or anything.)

There are no other fields in entire database named 'Note'.

The word 'Note' is a short text data type set in table.

I even created a new database with only one table and one field with the name "Note"...Same thing. Error if I try to use this word without brackets.

HELP.....!!!!!! AM I MISSING SOMETHING.

The word "Note" isn't a reserved word as far as I can find.

Whats wrong with the word "Note" ?????

Comment: Isn't this the answer to your own question ~ *"The word 'Note' is a short text data type set in table"*?

Comment: I have other fields with same data type 'short text', No problems

Comment: Sorry, that sentence isn't very clear. It sounds like you're saying *Note* is a data type

Comment: no problems assigning values without brackets, besides I changed name to JNote and it works without brackets and name was only thing changed, did not change data type in table.

Comment: I am saying the word itself, without brackets, is raising error somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The word `NOTE` is a reserved word, according to [Access 2007 reserved words and symbols](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx).

This from the "N" section of the reserved words from the link:

```
    NAME
    NewPassword
    NO
    Not
    Note
    NULL
    NUMBER, NUMERIC
```

You'll have to use the brackets.

Comment: Thank you, The lists of reserved words I was searching were not showing the word, so I was concerned I had a corrupt file or something. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the a reserved name like that you have to put a bracket around it.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, LastName, [Note]) VALUES ('Sam', 'Jones', 'Works Mondays Only');
```

Not a recommendation but its a workaround if you don't want to mess up what you have already created.